# How to prevent simultaneous login with same user on Active Directory?

Tags: security, authentication, active-directory, user-accounts

I don't want two users to be login with the same login name in the same time .
How to do this ?

I use Active Directory on a Windows Server 2012 R2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems Active Directory doesn't provide this functionality by default. However there is a [Technet Article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37839.active-directory-limit-concurrent-user-logins.aspx) explaining how to achieve this by using GPO/Logon Scripts.

Comment: I can't use this answer because some time that don't work . I am trying to do something without flag . For example a script who ask who is logged in each computers on the AD.

Answer (score 0):

One other answer :

Create a file when a user login and check for such file each time the login request is received  if file exists logoff, if file is not present Login and create the file.

http://abhishek.nagar.me/blogs/restrict-multiple-logins-domain-ad